# Access Firebase Realtime Database using Pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have recently started with pyrebase and I am having trouble in storing data depending on user and receiving it. After completing the authentication part I create a user ID as `user['idToken']`
And then pushed data by using

```
archer = {"name": "Sterling Archer", "agency": "Figgis Agency"} 
db.child("agents").push(archer, user['idToken'])
```

I assume that each user has different ID token which remains same even if we logout and relogin.  but when I am using

```
all_agents = db.child("agents").get(user['idToken']).val()
print(all_agentes)
```

It's printing all data stored in realtime database. Even which were stored by other users.

I tried reading all it's documentation, but I was unable to understand how to handle it.

What's wrong that I am doing in here and How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `user[localId]` instead of `user[idToken]` as it will create database for every different user separately